# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - Threaded Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I keep getting the following error : Segmentation fault (core dumped) . I found out the line of code that is causing the problem ( marked with a comment inside of the program) . Please tell me why this error is happening and how to fix it.

I've tried to dry run my code (on paper ) and see no logical errors (from my understanding).
*I have only recently got into coding and stackoverflow please guide me through how I can further improve my question , as well as my code . Thanks !*

```
class tree
{
struct node    // Creates a node for a tree
{
    int data;
    bool rbit,lbit;  // rbit/lbit= defines if right/left child of root is present or not
    node *left,*right;
};
public:
    node *head,*root;
    tree() // constructor initializes root and head  
    {
        root=NULL;
        head=createnode(10000);
    }
    node *createnode(int value)  
    {// Allocates memory for a node then initializes node with given value and returns that node
        node *temp=new node ;
        temp->data=value;
        temp->lbit=0;
        temp->rbit=0;
        temp->left=NULL;
        temp->right=NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    void insert(node *temp,int value) // Creates binary search tree node by node
    {
        if(root==NULL)  // Checking if tree is empty
        {
            root=createnode(value);  //Root now points to new memory location 
            head->left=root;
            head->lbit=1;
            root->left=head;//this line gives the segmentation fault (what i thought before correction) 
        }   

    }
    void inorder(node *root) // Inorder traversal of tree (this function is logically incorrect) 
    {
        if(root==NULL)
            return;
        inorder(root->left);
        cout<<root->data<<"\t";
        inorder(root->right);
    }
    void getdata()//Accepts data , creates a node through insert() , displays result through inorder()
    {
        int data;
        cout<<"Enter data"<<endl;
        cin>>data;  
        insert(root,data);
        inorder(root);
    }
 /*void inorder(node *root) // Working inorder code
{
    if(root->lbit==1)
    inorder(root->left);
    cout<<root->data<<"\t";
    if(root->rbit==1)
    inorder(root->right);
}*/
};
int main()
{

    tree t; // Tree Object 
    t.getdata();  // Calling getdata
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're asking if a given pointer is NULL, and then trying to access it? It's kinda like playing Russian Roulette, except rather than taking chances, you fill the gun with bullets to make sure you'll get shot.

Comment: That's why i created the variable temp( temp assigns a block of node memory via the function createnode(value) )  . I check if my root node is NULL and if it is I immediately assigned it to temp.  That means the root pointer is now pointing to a valid memory block . I am trying to access that memory block 's "left "pointer and assign it to a new address ( "head" node's address )

Comment: Sorry, missed the `root = temp` part. Anyway: you're calling `insert(root,data)`, yet the first argument of `insert` is `temp` itself which is immediately overwritten. You should think this through as it makes no sense.

Comment: Another thing that makes no sense: If `root` is not `NULL`, `insertnode()` does absolutely nothing, whatsoever, except leak memory.

Comment: Actually i've tried this code 3 times( 2 times in college and one time at home) , what I initially did was root=createnode(value) and had the same error both places . So I decided to do the code a bit differently this time around . Although this makes no sense , the code should at least work logically right? Once it at least shows me an output I'll brush up the code .

Comment: Obviously it is not logically correct. Logically correct code does not crash with a core-dump. Unfortunately, it is not possible for anyone to tell you why the shown code is logically incorrect. This is because in order to do so, the shown code must meet all the requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], and the shown code does not.

Comment: There is actually more to this code  ,  I have the else part to (if (root==NULL))  . All I'm trying to do with this prototype is to print to root node of a tree , which is not happening . After I print the root node , I can insert the rest of the code which creates the actual binary search tree .

Comment: It's obvious that there's more to the code. One very unique aspect of C++ is just because a program crashes on one particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ doesn't work this way. The bug can occur at any point before the crash, corrupting memory with a bad pointer dereference, or for any one of other myriad of reasons, but execution continues until some random point later, where the corrupted memory results in a crash. As such, staring at this line of code accomplishes absolutely nothing. Which is why a [mcve] is required, and without it, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: You are arguing with experts.  Feel free to carry on assuming that line is a problem, but the fact is that the pointer `temp` was just allocated with `new`, and so is guaranteed to be valid.  When you crash on `temp->left=head`, it means either `this` has somehow been deleted by another thread, you have memory corruption, or there is some other form of undefined behavior at play.  I wouldn't even be surprised if you never allocated a `tree` object and are performing all this on an uninitialized pointer.  If you're asked for more context, I suggest you provide it.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you people, obviously you guys have way more experience and knowledge  than I do . Im just saying what I observed (when i remove that line of code i get no errors ) .  In the main function I have allocated a tree object and called getdata with it.

Comment: I've made my code more readable and provided the main function as well

Comment: What is the point of `temp` argument of `insert`?`You don't use the passed value for anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the comments section largely reflects a miscommunication.  It's easy to believe that you are experiencing a crash *ON* that particular line.

This is not actually the case.  Instead what you have done is created a loop in your tree which leads to infinite recursion by the `inorder` function.  That causes a stack overflow which segfaults -- this would have been extremely easy to spot if you had just run your program with a debugger (such as gdb) attached.

```
temp = createnode(value);
if(root == NULL)
{
    root = temp;
    head->left = root;
    head->lbit = 1;
    temp->left = head;
}
```

Look at the loop you have just created:

```
head->left points to root
root->left == temp->left, which points to head
```

An inorder traversal will now visit:

```
root
  head
    root
      head
        root
          head
            ...
```

Since it never gets to the end of the left-branch, the function never outputs anything before overflowing the stack and crashing.

So no, your code is not logically correct.  There's a fundamental design flaw in it.  You need to rethink what you are storing in your tree and why.

Comment: Thank you !!! I will learn how to use a debugger . I've fixed the error in inorder , this time i checked if they have lbit/rbit=1 before calling the function instead of checking if root was NULL

Answer (score 1):

From the code,

```
    root=temp;  //Root now points to temp
    head->left=root;
    head->lbit=1;
    temp->left=head;// this line gives the segmentation fault
```

root is not pointing to temp. temp(pointer) is assigned to root(pointer).
head's left pointer is root, and temp's left is head (which means root's left is head). so in the function "inorder",

```
    void inorder(node *root) // Inorder traversal of tree
    {
        if(root==NULL)             <<<<<<
            return;
        inorder(root->left);
        cout<<root->data<<"\t";
        inorder(root->right);
    }
```

the argument node *root (left) is never NULL and the function never return.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information on exactly how this should work (what is `node.lbit` for example).

The question's `insert()` function will not work.  It's passing in a value which is immediately overwritten (among other issues).  There's no explanation of what `tree.head` is for, so it's ignored.  The fields `node.lbit` and `node.rbit` look to be superfluous flags of `node.left != NULL` (similarly for right).  These are omitted too.  The `insert()` is also not creating the tree properly.

```
void insert(int value) // Insert a value into the tree (at branch)
{
    // Create a new node to insert
    struct node *temp = createnode(value);

    if (root == NULL)  // Checking if tree is empty
    {
        root = temp;  //Root now points to temp
    }  
    else 
    {
        insertAtBranch(root, temp);
    }
}

// recursively find the leaf-node at which to insert the new node
void insertAtBranch(node *branch, node *new_node)
{
    // to create a BST, less-than go left
    if (new_node->value <= branch->value)
    {
        if (branch->left == NULL)
            branch->left = new_node;  // There's no left-branch, so it's the node
        else
            insertAtBranch(branch->left, new_node);  // go deeper to find insertion point
    }
    else // greater-than go right
    {
        if (branch->right == NULL)
            branch->right = new_node;
        else
            insertAtBranch(branch->right, new_node);
    }
}
```

Imagine how a binary tree works.  New nodes are only ever inserted at the edges.  So you look at a given node, and decide if this new-node is less or grater than the one you're looking at (unless the tree is empty, of course).

Say the `new-node.value` is less than the `branch-node.value`, you want to branch left.  Still with the same node, if it doesn't have a left-branch `(node.left == NULL)`, the new node *is* the left branch.  Otherwise you need to travel down the left-branch and check again.

I would have made `node` a class, and used a constructor to at least set the default properties and `value`.  But that's not a big deal.